# How can I return the value from my Task<string> in my iOS Dependecy Service [Xamarin.Forms.iOS]?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am running a function that works correctly and I get the correct value but I am having issues figuring out how I can get the value (that is a string with text)from my DI Service back to my shared code. When I type the result out in the log in the function below I get the correct value:

```
RecognitionTask = SpeechRecognizer.GetRecognitionTask (LiveSpeechRequest, (SFSpeechRecognitionResult result, NSError err) =>
        {
            thetextresult = result.BestTranscription.FormattedString;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(thetextresult); //I get the correct value
        });
```

(If I await this code above can that solve my problem maybe?, if so how can i await a result from a string?)

My current problem is that after this code I work with the log once again to see if I can reach the log again after this function:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Do I reach this?");
```

But I cannot reach this so the `return thetextresult` in the end of the function does not get reached which means that I do not get value in return in my shared code.

This is how the code looks:

Function in my iOS DependecyService:

```
        var node = AudioEngine.InputNode;
        var recordingFormat = node.GetBusOutputFormat(0);

        node.InstallTapOnBus(0, 1024, recordingFormat, (AVAudioPcmBuffer buffer, AVAudioTime when) =>
        {
            LiveSpeechRequest.Append(buffer);
        });

        AudioEngine.Prepare();
        NSError error;
        AudioEngine.StartAndReturnError(out error);

        RecognitionTask = SpeechRecognizer.GetRecognitionTask (LiveSpeechRequest, (SFSpeechRecognitionResult result, NSError err) =>
        {
            thetextresult = result.BestTranscription.FormattedString;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(thetextresult); //value gets out correctly.
        });


    }

  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Do I reach this?"); //this does not get reached when i do the function.
  return thetextresult; //which means that this is not returning the value
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface ISoundToSpeak
{
    Task<string> SpeechToTextAsync();
}
```

How i use it on my contentpage, function:

```
async Task <string>WaitForSpeech()
    {
        return await DependencyService.Get<ISoundToSpeak>().SpeechToTextAsync();
    }
```

a button:

```
async void speakClick(object s, EventArgs a)
    {
        var speechText = await WaitForSpeech();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(speechText); //so with this current code i do not get the text out in my shared code. 
    }
```

Comment: this is not a custom renderer.  It is a DI service.

Comment: @Jason Ah ok! Thought you called it a renderer if you make specific code for a platform! Thanks a lot for the info :)

Comment: @Jason When it comes to the issue, do you know how to fix it? I am trying to "await" the `thetextresult = result.BestTranscription.FormattedString;` i get from the `GetRecognitionTask`but as it is a string i cannot await the result. If that gets fixed maybe that will solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function StartRecord is async but I don't see any await inside it. SpeechRecognizer.GetRecognitionTask is a task with callback. You should be able to reach "Do I reach this?" but the result of thetextresult is not going to be there as you don't wait till GetRecognitionTask completes. You should either await somehow on RecognitionTask or not return textresult from a function but call your shared code from callback.

What worked at the end is providing a callback function to SpeechToTextAsync.

Comment: If you want more concrete fix please publish your complete solution.

Comment: why do you call it renderer?

Comment: My bad, it is a DI Service. I alwaysthought you called all specific code renderers but yeah this is a Dependency service.

Comment: I will take a look Monday

Comment: It lloks like SFSpeechRecognizer is for iOS 10 only. Sorry I don't have yet iOS 10 tools installed

Comment: No Nuget! Make sure to use `using Speech;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129173/discussion-between-yuri-s-and-carlos-rodrigez).

Comment: Excellent :) Works very well with a callback!! Awesome job